# How to do escaping idiomatically in Scala

Tags: scala

Suppose I am writing a simple function to escape XML string.

```
val map = Map('&' -> "&amp;", '<' -> "&lt;", '>' -> "&gt;") // ... and more
def escape(str: String): String = {
  val w = new java.io.StringWriter()
  for(c <- str) if (map.contains(c)) w.write(map(c)) else w.write(c); 
  w.toString
}
```

It does not look *idiomatically* in Scala and besides, I do not know how to deal with the `map`, which maps characters to escaping strings. How would you suggest me fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Real life solution**

Just use [`scala.xml.Utility.escape`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.xml.Utility%24):

```
scala> scala.xml.Utility.escape(foo)
res7: String = &amp;foo&lt;bar&gt;hello
```

**If you're still interested in doing it yourself:**

First of all, there's no need to repeat the `&` and `;` parts in the escapes map:

```
scala> val Escapes = Map('&' -> "amp", '<' -> "lt", '>' -> "gt")
```

(it's simpler and faster to have them in tho... but since you seem to have asked this question for learning purposes...)

```
scala> def escapeChar(c: Char) = Escapes.get(c).map { x => s"&$x;" }
escapeChar: (c: Char)Option[String]

scala> def escapeStr(s: String) = s.flatMap { c => escapeChar(c).getOrElse(c.toString) }
escapeStr: (s: String)String

scala> escapeStr("&foo<bar>hello")
res9: String = &amp;foo&lt;bar&gt;hello
```

...you could also just inline the `escapeChar(c: Char)` function, but I think it's more readable this way.

In case you're interested: this works by treating the string as a sequence of chars; you `flatMap` over it, which allows you to map each char into more than one char (a `String`); `flatMap` then joins all the emitted strings into a single string. Characters that don't need escaping are trivially mapped to one-char strings.

Answer (score 5):

Just for a sake of completeness -- basically the same solution, but with <s>function</s> method in place of the map:

```
def escape(char: Char) = char match {
     case '&' => "&amp;"
     case '<' => "&lt;"
     case '>' => "&gt;"
     case noEscaping  => noEscaping.toString 
}
val str = "hit & run"
str.flatMap(escape)
// hit &amp; run
```

Comment: actually, technically speaking, `Map('&' -> "amp").isInstanceOf[Char => String]`... so solutions using `Map` already are using a function; but I do agree that it's way more readable than `Map` + a doorman function.

Comment: @ErikAllik well, yeah, the right term here could be **method**, not function

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
scala> val map = Map[Char, Seq[Char]]('&' -> "&amp;", 
       '<' -> "&lt;", 
       '>' -> "&gt;").withDefault(x => Seq(x))
map: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,Seq[Char]] = Map(& -> &amp;, < -> &lt;, > -> &gt;)

scala> "&foo<bar>hello".flatMap(map)
res2: String = &amp;foo&lt;bar&gt;hello
```

OR

```
scala> val map = Map('&' -> "&amp;", '<' -> "&lt;", '>' -> "&gt;").withDefault(identity)

scala> "&foo<bar>hello".map(map).mkString
res3: String = &amp;foo&lt;bar&gt;hello
```

Comment: `.map(map).mkString` -> `.flatMap(map)` wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @Erik  Did you try yourself?

Comment: Actually nevermind my comment. I forgot about the first variant you posted :P