# How to implement "unescape" in Scala?

Tags: scala

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21855816/how-to-do-escaping-idiomatically-in-scala)

Thanks to the answers I realized that the `escape` function is *actually* a `flatMap` with argument `f:Char => Seq[Char]` to map escaped characters to escaping sequences (see the answers).

Now I wonder how to implement `unescape` as a *reverse* operation to `escape`. I guess tt should be a reverse to `flatMap` with argument `f:Seq[Char] => Char`. Does it make sense ? How would you suggest implement `unescape` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess tt should be a reverse to flatMap with a function f:Seq[Char] => Char. Does it make sense ?

Not really. What should your inverse function `f:Seq[Char] => Char` return on `"abc"`? It should apply to *any* sequence of characters and return a single character. You could try using `PartialFunction[Seq[Char], Char]` instead, but you'll run into other problems. Do you apply it to every subsequence of your input?

The more general solution would be to use `foldLeft` with the accumulator type containing both the built-up part of the result and the escaping sequence, something like (untested):

```
def unescape(str: String) = {
  val result = str.foldLeft[(String, Option[String])](("", None)) { case ((acc, escapedAcc), c) => 
    (c, escapedAcc) match {
      case ('&', None) =>
        (acc, Some(""))
      case (_, None) =>
        (acc + c, None)
      case ('&', Some(_)) =>
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("nested escape sequences")
      case (';', Some(escapedAcc1)) => 
        (acc + unescapeMap(escapedAcc1), None)
      case (_,  Some(escapedAcc1)) =>
        (acc, Some(escapedAcc1 + c))
    }
  }

  result match {
    case (escaped, None) =>
      escaped
    case (_, Some(_)) => 
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("unfinished escape sequence")
  }
}

val unescapeMap = Map("amp" -> "&", "lt" -> "<", ...)
```

(It's much more efficient to use `StringBuilder`s for the accumulators, but this is simpler to understand.)

But for this specific case you could just split the string on `&`, then split each part except first on `;`, and get the parts you want this way.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a follow-up to [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21856087/247623) to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21855816/247623) whose follow-up this question is... use `scala.xml.Utility.unescape`:

```
val sb = new StringBuilder
scala.xml.Utility.unescape("amp", sb)
println(sb.toString) // prints &
```

or if you just want to unescape once and throw away the `StringBuilder` instance:

```
scala.xml.Utility.unescape("amp", new StringBuilder).toString // returns "&"
```

This just parses individual escapes; you'll have to build a parser of entire XML strings around it yourself—the accepted answer seems to provide that bit but fails to not reinvent the `scala.xml.Utility` wheel— or use something from `scala.xml` instead.